# how to create a desktop environemt

Tags: development, desktop-environments, libraries

I want to create a desktop environment for Ubuntu and Linux
can you tell me how to do that i want the best easiest way to do that.
can i use qt Linux embedded to do that if it is then i want to use that only
tell me which library how it can be done using python which packages to download and import
i want to work more on main things rather than other things i can use c++ too but adding library to c++ is a big pain especially with ides such as eclipse , net beans if i can do it with qt easily tell the system package

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001892/how-to-create-a-simple-desktop-environment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why create a Desktop Environment from scratch if there are so many free ones available?

Pick one that you like, grab its sources, and modify it to your tastes. No need to reinvent the wheel. Besides, a DE is not a 1-man job... It takes years, and hundreds (thousands?) of developers.

Studying an existent DE is the best way to learn how to build your own, if you really want to. If you like working with QT, then [KDE](http://www.kde.org/) might be a good starting point.

Last but not least, [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) and [MATE](http://mate-desktop.org/) are 2 new DEs, and both need developers as motivated as you. Why not join forces instead?

Answer (score 0):

Cinnamon is a KDE fork and MATE is forked from Gnome2. even the pros never started from scratch. get the sources from one that's a close approximate to what you want and modify it to your liking